# OSX Terminal delete last 7 Characters of Filename

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Hi is there an easy way to rename a bunch of files like:

```
A_16-25-55-313.txt
```

and

```
B_16-25-55-313.txt
```

so that all the Files in the Folder look like:

```
A_16-25.txt
```

and

```
B_16-25.txt
```

In this example case I would have to get rid of the last 7 Characters before the extension.
I used the OS X terminal
and tried stuff like:

```
for i in *.txt do set fName==$i
do mv $fName $fName:~0,-7.txt
```

which didn't work and:

```
for i in *
do
j=`echo $i | sed -e ’s/.......$//‘`
mv $i $j
done
```

which did not work as well.

Comment: Got `rename` on OSX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what reference you are using for `bash`, but the following is what you want:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    # Get the filename minus the .txt suffix 
    drop_ext=${i%.txt}
    # Drop the last seven characters, then readd the suffix
    fName=${drop_ext%???????}.txt
    mv "$i" "$fName"
done
```

Actually, given that you know the suffix is 4 characters, you can just drop the last 11 characters right away before adding the suffix back.

```
for i in *.txt; do
    mv "$i" "${i%???????????}.txt"
done
```

Comment: thx that works, could you tell me why this works when I'm entering it line by line into the terminal but not when I'm making a .sh or .command file ? `line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'` and `line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: I'd say you're missing a quotation mark somewhere, but it's hard to say more without seeing your code.

Comment: no you where right I missed something in the code :-)